# Determine (with justification) whether the series converges or diverges. If convergent find the sum.

Tags: sequences-and-series

Consider:

$$\sum_{k = 1}^{\infty} (\frac{(\arcsin(0.5))^k+2^{-k})}{2})$$

This is what I tried:

I know that by a theorem if $$\sum_{k = 1}^{\infty} a_n$$ and $$\sum_{k = 1}^{\infty} b_n$$ are convergent series, and C is a constant then $$\sum_{k = 1}^{\infty} (a_n+b_n)$$ will be equal to $$\sum_{k = 1}^{\infty} a_n+ \sum_{k = 1}^{\infty} b_n$$

So what I'm thinking of doing is first splitting up the series into two:

$$\sum_{k = 1}^{\infty} (\frac{(arcsin(0.5))^k)}{2}) + \sum_{k = 1}^{\infty} (\frac{2^{-k}}{2})$$

Then I could take the limit of my b(subn) and show it is going to infinity, thus, by the theorem the whole thing must be going towards infinity. But, Im not sure if I'm missing something big because I do not think the arcsin would be in the problem for no reason.

EDIT: Actually if I take the limit off my b(subn) it would go to 0. So then I would need to take the limit of the first one as well...

Comment: Use braces, `2^{-k}` -> $2^{-k}$. And `a_n` for $a_n$, plus `\arcsin` for $\arcsin$.

Comment: For the problem: You probably have learned about geometric series.

Comment: Yes of course, but this does not seem like one at all. Can I tell simply because it is being raised to k?

Comment: You have a constant factor, and something (also constant) raised to the $k$-th power. That's a geometric series.

Comment: Two geometric series added.

Comment: So my constant factor would be 1/2 then? And then I would be able to pull that in front of the series to get something like: $$1/2\sum_{k = 1}^{\infty} ({(\arcsin(0.5))^k+2^{-k})})$$

Comment: Now I have this: $$1/2\sum_{k = 1}^{\infty} {\arcsin(0.5)^k} + 1/2\sum_{k = 1}^{\infty} {2^{-k}}$$

Comment: Im not sure if this would be ok to do next, since they are both convergent as k goes to infinity, could I take a limit of both and show that they both converge to 0, therefore my answer would be 0?

Comment: Wait I should take one r = arcsin(0.5) and another as r = 2 and then go from there to get the answer!

Answer (score 0):

1. Split the series into two different series

$$\sum_{k = 1}^{\infty} (\frac{(\arcsin(0.5))^k)}{2}) + \sum_{k = 1}^{\infty} (\frac{2^{-k}}{2})$$

2. Pull out 1/2 from both

$$1/2\sum_{k = 1}^{\infty} {\arcsin(0.5)^k} + 1/2\sum_{k = 1}^{\infty} {2^{-k}}$$

3. Notice it is now a geometric series so for $a_n$ r = $\arcsin(0.5)$ and for $b_n$ r = 2
4. Divide both answers in half and both r's will be less than one, so the series converges.